# md-button-toggle-group is clickable even after marking [disabled]="true"

Tags: angular

This is my HTML code for button.

```
<md-button-toggle-group
    [disabled]="true"
    [name]="name"
    [(ngModel)]="value"
    [class]="options.class">
    <md-button-toggle
        *ngFor="let option of options.items"
        [value]="option.value"
        [class]="option.class"
        [disabled]="true"
        (click)="onClick(option.value)">
    </md-button-toggle>
</md-button-toggle-group>
```

This code is allowing to click button. :(

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: <md-button-toggle-group
    [disabled]="options.disabled"
    [name]="name"
    [(ngModel)]="value"
    [class]="options.class">
    <md-button-toggle
        *ngFor="let option of options.items"
        [value]="option.value"
        [class]="option.class"
        [disabled]="option.disabled"
        (click)="options.disabled ? null : onClick(option.value)">
        {{option.label}}
    </md-button-toggle>
</md-button-toggle-group>

It worked for me .

Answer (score 1):

Try removing [] from disabled since you are assigning a direct value to it. Or try using a variable instead of direct value `[disabled]="isDisabled"`.